# Duplicated icons in CListViewCtrl

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I know that the main problem comes from recursively calling `FindFile()`. With recursively calling this function, my `i` becomes 0. But I don't understand how I can fix this problem.

If possible, give advice on how to fix this bug without completely reworking all the functions below. Or provide a link where you can read about the correct initialization of icons in `CListViewCtrl`.

```
void Finder::FindFile(CString szPath)
{
    HIMAGELIST hSmall{};
    CFindFile F;
    CString S = szPath + TEXT("\\*.*");
    int i = 0;
    BOOL bFlag = F.FindFile(S);
    if (!bFlag)
    {
        MessageBox(TEXT("Error"), TEXT("File not found"), 0);
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if (F.IsDots() == TRUE)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if (F.IsDirectory() == TRUE)
                {
                    View_List(F.GetFileName(), i, F.GetFilePath());
                    i++;
                    FindFile(F.GetFilePath());
                }
                else
                {
                    View_List(F.GetFileName(), i, F.GetFilePath());
                    i++;
                }
            }
        } while (F.FindNextFileW());
        F.Close();
        InitListViewImage(i, S);
    }
}

void Finder::View_List(CString name, int i, CString path)
{
    CString nameWithoutEx=std::get<0>(Split(name));
    CString extention= std::get<1>(Split(name));
    lvItem.mask = LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.state = 0;
    lvItem.stateMask = 0;
    lvItem.iItem = i;
    lvItem.iImage = i;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.pszText = (LPWSTR)nameWithoutEx.GetString();
    lvItem.cchTextMax = nameWithoutEx.GetLength();
    myListView.InsertItem(&lvItem);
    myListView.SetItemText(i, 1, extention.GetString());
    myListView.SetItemText(i, 2, path.GetString());
}

std::tuple<CString, CString> Finder::Split(CString buf)
{
    CString tmp = buf;
    if (buf.Find(TEXT(".")) == -1)
    {
        return { buf.GetString(),TEXT("Directory") };
    }
    else
    {
        int index = buf.Find(TEXT("."))+1;
        if (buf.Find(TEXT("."),index) != -1)
        {
            while (buf.Find(TEXT("."), index) != -1)
            {
                index = buf.Find(TEXT("."), index)+1;
            }
        }
        buf.Delete(index-1, buf.GetLength());
        tmp.Delete(0, index-1);
        return{ buf.GetString(),tmp.GetString() };
    }
}


BOOL Finder::InitListViewImage(int size, CString path)
{
    CFindFile F;
    HIMAGELIST hSmall;
    SHFILEINFO lp{};
    hSmall = ImageList_Create(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), ILC_MASK | ILC_COLOR32, size, 1);
    bool hFind = F.FindFile(path);
    if (!hFind)
    {
        MessageBox(TEXT("Error"), TEXT("File not found"), MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if (F.IsDots() == TRUE)
            {
                continue;
            }
            DWORD num = GetFileAttributesW(F.GetFilePath());
            SHGetFileInfoW(F.GetFilePath(), num, &lp, sizeof(lp), SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES);
            ImageList_AddIcon(hSmall, lp.hIcon);
            DestroyIcon(lp.hIcon);
        } while (F.FindNextFileW());
        F.Close();
    }
    myListView.SetImageList(hSmall, 1);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear from your question what you expect from this code and what you get. There are 4 functions, but no `main` or other code, that can be considered as starting point.

Comment: I calling only FindFile() in my main function. All another functions only support this function. So, there is no reason to put here code of my main function.

Comment: It's still unclear from your question what you expect from this code and what you get.

Comment: In FindFile() function i searching files. If i found the file in  the desired directory i calling View_List() function to insert file information in my CListViewCtrl. But, if i found folder, i calling again FindFile() function for folder in my Directory, to get all info about files in that folder. And, only after i took all info about all files in my Directory, i calling function. InitListViewImage() to insert icons for my file info. 
But my Icons are incorrect, they are repeat. 
Icons repeating because of my variable I, that becoming 0 when i recursive calling my FindFile().

Comment: variable I using as a index for image. But because it becoming 0, everything doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the value of `i` as a reference to `FindFile` so that when you call it recursively the value continues to increment.

```
void Finder::FindFile(CString szPath, int& i)
{
    HIMAGELIST hSmall{};
    CFindFile F;
    CString S = szPath + TEXT("\\*.*");
//    int i = 0;  <-- not declared here, as it is now an argument
    BOOL bFlag = F.FindFile(S);
    if (!bFlag)
    {
        MessageBox(TEXT("Error"), TEXT("File not found"), 0);
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if (F.IsDots() == TRUE)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if (F.IsDirectory() == TRUE)
                {
                    View_List(F.GetFileName(), i, F.GetFilePath());
                    i++;
                    FindFile(F.GetFilePath(), i); // <-- pass i to the recursive function
                }
                else
                {
                    View_List(F.GetFileName(), i, F.GetFilePath());
                    i++;
                }
            }
        } while (F.FindNextFileW());
        F.Close();
        InitListViewImage(i, S);
    }
}
```

When you call `FindFile` from your main function or wherever, you need to give it a variable to use as the starting point, e.g.

```
main()
{
    int i = 0;
    FindFile("C:\", i);
}
```